# Template argument deduction for an argument of a function type

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following program.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f( void ( *fn )( T ) )
{
    fn( 42 );
}

void g( int x )
{
    std::cout << "g( " << x << " );\n";
}

int main()
{
    f( g );
}
```

The program compiles successfully and its output is

```
g( 42 );
```

Now let's rename the non-template function `g` to `f`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f( void ( *fn )( T ) )
{
    fn( 42 );
}

void f( int x )
{
    std::cout << "f( " << x << " );\n"; 
}

int main()
{
    f( f );
}
```

Now the program is not compiled by gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20200 and clang HEAD 10.0.0 but compiled successfully by Visual C++ 2019..

For example the compiler gcc issues the following set of messages.

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:22:10: error: no matching function for call to 'f(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   22 |     f( f );
      |          ^
prog.cc:4:6: note: candidate: 'template<class T> void f(void (*)(T))'
    4 | void f( void ( *fn )( T ) )
      |      ^
prog.cc:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cc:22:10: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
   22 |     f( f );
      |          ^
prog.cc:14:6: note: candidate: 'void f(int)'
   14 | void f( int x )
      |      ^
prog.cc:14:13: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'int'
   14 | void f( int x )
      |         ~~~~^
```

So a question arises: should the code be compiled and what is the reason that the code is not compiled by gcc and clang?

Comment: [See for yourself on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cRGJ-k)

Comment: Note: in the first example, passing `g` (instead of `&g`) to the function template causes a type decay (a function lvalue reference decays to a pointer to a function: `void(&)(T)` => `void(*)(T)`). This implicit convertion happens because there is no other `f` overload with a better match. In the second example, there is an ambiguity which `f` you want to actually call because ... it doesn't know which `f` is the argument either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would seem to me that gcc and clang are correct. This should not compile. The function parameter from which you'd like `T` to be deduced becomes a non-deduced context here the moment the argument supplied is an overload set that contains a function template [[temp.deduct.type]/5.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#5.5):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> - […]
> - A function parameter for which argument deduction cannot be done because the associated function argument is a function, or a set of overloaded functions ([over.over]), and one or more of the following apply:
>
>   - […]
>   - the set of functions supplied as an argument contains one or more function templates.
> - […]

Thus, `T` cannot be deduced and the other overload is not viable due to there being no conversion; exactly what gcc says…

Answer (score 0):

These are two overloaded functions and non-template function is should be selected compare 
to templated function, so f(int x) was selected hence passing a function as an argument
in the function which int must be passed is impossible .
and the below should work. Thanks

```
void f( void ( *fn )( int ) ){
  fn( 42 );
}
void f( int x ){
    std::cout << "f( " << x << " );\n";
  }

  int main(){

     f( f );
  }
```

Comment: Non-template functions are preferred only when there is otherwise a tie during overload resolution.  The question’s code doesn’t get to that point: there is never a specialization `void f<int>(void(int))` generated so as to do overload resolution at *either* level.